# Atualizar página após ação

Tags: php, script

Tenho uma função para alterar registros no banco e uso um modal para mostrar mensagem de sucesso ou erro na alteração.

A questão é que consigo deletar, mas gostaria que após essa função fosse concluída a página automaticamente desse um refresh.

```
elseif(isset($_GET['Acao']) && $_GET['Acao'] == 'Alterar') {
   $Id = $_GET['Id'];
     $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE vendas SET Mostrar = '0' WHERE Id = '$Id' ");

     if ($sql){
       echo '<script>modal({type: "inverted", title: "INFORMAÇÃO!", text: "Aterado com Sucesso!"});
       </script>';}
      else {  
        echo '<script>modal({type: "error", title: "Ops!", text: "Erro ao Alterar!"});</script>';             
}
```

---

```
<table class="lista-clientes" width="100%""> 
<tbody>     
    <tr>
        <td align="center"></td>
    <td> 

    <select class="select_styled">
        <option value="">'.$dados['Pessoa'].' </option>
        <option value="">'.$dados['Venda'].'</option>
    </select>
    <center>
        <a href="?Id='.$dados['Id'].'&Acao=Alterar" class="btn btn-follow" style="text-decoration:none;">
            <span>Remover!</span>
        </a>
    </center>
    </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oi Léo, enquanto acredito que [a resposta do Rafael](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173625/100) resolva seu problema (você pode usar `location.reload();` do lado do JavaScript como função de *callback* da modal) o fato de você precisar fazer isso me parece estranho. Se você já tem o `id` da venda, por que não simplesmente remover as informações da página usando JavaScript? Talvez você esteja querendo fazer algo com Ajax...

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar `JavaScript` e `php` para recarregar a página.

#### Javascript

```
location.reload();
```

#### PHP

```
header('Refresh:0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, o que você precisa é disso:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.opener.location.href='home.php'; window.close()"><input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Fechar Janela"></a>
```

Coloque esse código na página de confirmação e esse link ao usuário clicar ele atualiza a página que você define em `"window.opener.location.href='home.php'`

Comment: sim sim, a questão é essa  teria alguma forma de contar alguns segunos antes de atualizar ou ao eu fechar o modal

Comment: porque se eu só atualizar ele fica com o ?Id=11&Acao=Alterar  no navegador e exibe o modal

Answer (score 0):

Para recarregar uma página via javascript você pode usar uma das seguintes opções:

#### Javascript 1.0

```
window.location.href = window.location.pathname + "pagina";
```

> Cria entrada no histórico de páginas

#### Javascript 1.1

```
window.location.replace(window.location.pathname + "pagina");
```

> Não cria entrada no histórico de páginas

#### Javascript 1.2

```
window.location.reload();
```

> Recarrega página do cache

```
window.location.reload(false);
```

> Recarrega página do cache

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

> Recarrega página do servidor (força novo GET)